# How to run SQL queries in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, string, loops

How can I run this SQL query multiple times in a loop, where I replace the word 'pubs' with another word during each iteration. Is there a way to store an array of strings and loop through them?

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE category='pubs'
```

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's usually better performance-wise to do bulk or batch queries than queries in a loop, since you can save round trip calls to the DB.

Consider instead doing something like `SELECT * from businesses WHERE category IN ('pubs', ...)`, or if you plan to iterate over all categories, retrieve all item rows and programmatically use `category` in the returned models to do what you need to with them.

If you absolutely must use a loop, you can look at the [loop documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html).

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need a loop to run them rather use a `IN` clause to include all the possible condition values like

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE category IN ('pubs','subs','nubs')
```